# how to check load time of any website using java code?

Tags: java

I am developing an URL monitoring application for checking the URL's of my application.
I can check the connection by response code in java code.
But I am unable to check whether the application is slow or not??

I have done research. I found JQuery solution. but that is not my concern bcs that is to be applied on web application itself.
But I want to make a core java application that will be deployed in task manager to check URL's regularly on Windows server.

Please suggest me if any API exixt to do so. or any logic to check speed of loading of any web application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: get the time (ex. new Date()).  Send the desired http request to load the page.  get the time again.  Load time == the difference between the first time and the second time.

Comment: @DwB `System.nanoTime()` is the standard way to measure time durations. If you only want millisecond precision for whatever reason, `System.currentTimeMillis()` gives you the same as `new Date()`, in a more direct form.